# RxJS unsubscribe from inner observable when the source completes

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a function that returns observable that automatically unsubscribe when some internal thing happens using a Subject. Here is a simple version that shows the issue:

```
const subject = new Subject();

const source = fromEvent(document.querySelector("h1"), "click").pipe(
  takeUntil(subject)
);

fromEvent(document.querySelector("p"), "click").subscribe(() => {
  subject.next();
});
```

The issue is that if someone subscribes `source` and uses higher-order observable, it will not subscribe from the inner observable when the `Subject` emits:

```
source.pipe(mergeMap(() => interval(1000))).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

There is a way to solve this issue without forcing the consumer to call `unsubscribe`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `source` completing doesn't mean the currently running interval(s) end. If you want to kill the inner observables thing when source closes, you can do that, you'll just want to multicast `source` to avoid creating more `h1` event listeners.

```js
const subject = new Subject();

const source = fromEvent(document.querySelector("h1"), "click").pipe(
  takeUntil(subject)
);

const sharedSource = source.pipe(share());
const emitOnComplete = last(null, null);
const sourceIsDone = sharedSource.pipe(emitOnComplete);

sharedSource.pipe(
  mergeMap(() => interval(1000)),
  takeUntil(sourceIsDone)
);
```

Comment: I need the takeUntil to be on the source, not the one that uses it.

Comment: Updated answer to take feedback into account.