# RxJS takeUntil before higher-order observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am using the `takeUntil` operator before higher-order observable:

```
import { of, Subject, fromEvent, interval } from "rxjs";
import { takeUntil, mergeMap } from "rxjs/operators";

const subject = new Subject();

const source = fromEvent(document.querySelector("h1"), "click");

fromEvent(document.querySelector("p"), "click").subscribe(() => {
  subject.next();
});

source
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(subject),
    mergeMap(() => interval(1000))
  )
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

But we this code, I have a memory leak, because it does not unsubscribe from the `interval`. I can move it to be at the end of the chain, but this is error-prone. Developers can easily make this mistake. Is there a way to keep it like this, for example, and unsubscribe from the `interval`?

Comment: You have to do this yourself

Comment: No. For the same reason that the completion of the source - `of` - in this example does not complete the observable composed from it: `const composed  = of(42).pipe(mergeMap(() => interval(1e3)))`

Comment: @cartant, but this isn't supposed to be a chain? The `mergeMap` subscribes to the `of` observable, and when it gets a complete notification, it should complete. The same as it gets a `next` notification and subscribes.

Comment: It is a chain, but ask yourself what would happen in the example I gave in the above comment if the completion of `of` effected the immediate completion of the composed observable. More info here: https://ncjamieson.com/avoiding-takeuntil-leaks/

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: I answered this question for you when you asked it earlier this week :) [RxJS unsubscribe from inner observable when the source completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61462806/rxjs-unsubscribe-from-inner-observable-when-the-source-completes)

Answer (score 0):

To put `takeUntil` as the latest operator of pipe is a normal thing when using `mergeMap` or any other operator. When people put it as the first operator they should understand why they do it.

For example in a stop-watch rxjs example `takeUntil` isn't the latest, because it should be in the middle to support new start clicks.

```js
interval(1000).pipe(
  skipUntil(this.start),
  takeUntil(this.stop$),
  repeat(),
);
```

You can:

- use ts-lint check [rxjs-no-unsafe-takeuntil](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-tslint-rules)
- use a lib such as [ngx-auto-unsubscribe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-auto-unsubscribe)
- put notes in readme for developers
- use code reviews

But of course people should understand purpose of the code they write :)